# Post index for posts with several conditionals (categories, language, tags) in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'd like to have several post-indexes (indices?) on my Jekyll-powered website for several categories *and* languages, meaning more than one conditional.

My posts have YAML frontmatter including:

```
categories:
   - research
   - blog
lang: en
```

Now I'd like a post index, for, say all research posts in english.

I can do:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if post.lang == 'en' and post.categories contains 'research' %}
        {{ post.title }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That, however, screws up such niceties as limits and sort by year etc. For limiting the number of posts (etc.), Jekyll still seems to be looking at the *whole* list of posts, not just for whom the conditional applies.

Something like this pseudocode would be ideal:
    {% for post in site.posts where post.lang == 'en' and post.categories contains 'research' %}

Any thoughts?

Ps.: I can't use any plugins; want it to be GH Pages compatible.
Pps.: I know I could use language as a category, but that doesn't feel right -- these are different pieces of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this:

```
 {% assign resindex = site.posts | where: "category", "research", | where: "lang", "en" | sort: "title" %}
 {% for post in resindex limit:4 %} 
 <div>
 <p><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title | truncate: 52 }}</a></p>
  </div> 
 {% endfor %}
```

Though I am fairly confused by the use of category and categories and when you can/should use them. For my example category worked, but in my front matter I have: category: mycategory and am only using one. But the rest of the code should work, and you can limit and sort.